# В чём ошибка в классе?

Tags: php

Ругается на строку `$this->db = $connection;` и говорит что констунтное выражение содержит недопустимые операции. Я не могу понять что за константное выражение и недопустимые операции.

> Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations in...

```
class DB
{
    public function check() {
        echo "Проверка пройдена";
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(DB $connection = new DB()) {
        $this->db = $connection;
    }
    public function say() {
        return $this->db->check();
    }
}

$var = new MyClass();
$var->say();
```

Comment: И какая у вас версия PHP ? 5.6 ? Думаю у вас проблема в $connection = new DB(), не инициализируется

Comment: @Arsen я в онлайн-песочнике делал, там PHP 7.0.3 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6846a5c6375435230e9168053f9888c3e395895b

Comment: А почему бы просто не унаследовать класс DB?

Comment: а почему не так ?  - `    public function __construct(DB $connection = NULL) {
        $this->db = $connection ?: new DB() ;
    }`

Comment: @splash58 в комментарии к ответу Arsen я объяснил что это затруднит Юнит-тестирование и это противоречит паттерну, согласно которому объект должен прийти в класс уже готовый, а не создаваться в нём

Comment: присылайте готовый - будет он использоваться, а не пришлете, создастся новый

Comment: В моём коде та же логика, что в вашем вопросе, запись другая

Comment: @splash58 только в случае юнит-тестирования у вас ничего не создастся ))) И подменить объект тестовой БД не получится

Comment: вы умными словами меня не пугайте. Вы создаете новый объект, если он не передан, или используете переданный. Тоже делает мой код. В чем разница?

Comment: очевидно, пхп уведомляет вас о том, что нельзя писать выражения для значения параметра по умолчанию, и что там позволяются только константы. Так что либо пишите как говорит @splash58 либо, константой имя класса подключения будет, из которого при наличии дефолтного конструктора можно его и создать.

Comment: `new DB()` это вам тоже не внедрение зависимости. почти полный эквивалент того что предлагает @splash58, только у него потенциально можно отловить исключения и ошибки, в вашем потенциальном код такое не получится. Для заивисомтей вам по хорошему надо указать имя класса, который хотите получить на входе, а не создавать его экземпляр. А коли уж создаете, то не важно в каком именно месте.

Comment: @Deonis Это нарушает приницпы SOLID

Answer (score 0):

Думаю правильнее так будет, как пример։

```
<?php

class DB
{
    public function check() {
        echo "Проверка пройдена";
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db =  new DB();
    }
    public function say() {
        return $this->db->check();
    }
}

$var = new MyClass();
$var->say();
```

> Метод 2

```
<?php
class DB
{
    public function check() {
        echo "Проверка пройдена";
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct($connection) {
        $this->db = $connection;
    }
    public function say() {
        return $this->db->check();
    }
}

$var = new MyClass(new DB());
$var->say();
```

Comment: В классическом dependency injection http://h-type.com/filez/lj/articles/di/ в класс уже должен передаваться готовый объект, а в вашем примере вы создаёте объект внутри класса, это сильно помешает вам, например, при Unit-тестировании. Можно было бы выйти из ситуации так: `$var = new MyClass($connection = new DB());` но тогда мне каждый раз при создании экземпляра класса вручную придётся передавать туда объект, а это неудобно.

Comment: ну можете просто передать при вызове метода и получить в __construct(DB $connection), должно работать норм

Comment: Ок, где я должен создать объект $connection в этом случае?

Comment: @fosh4455 в ответ добавил второй метод

Comment: @Arsen зависимость это не наследование

Comment: @teran - даже сам не заметил как добавил extends )))

Comment: теперь надо всегда создавать класс подключения самому. что также не имеет общего с "внедрением зависимостей"